# Javascript pop up hide when click outside and show if links are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

need help.. this is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Snippet/5XM97/).

it shows a pop up on first load..

the problem is when i click on the pop up it hides..how do i prevent this.. also when i click on a link it should show the pop up again and when i click outside of the pop up it will hide..

Script

```
  $(document).ready( function() {

        // When site loaded, load the Popupbox First
        loadPopupBox();

        $("#popupBoxClose").click( function () {
        alert('hello');
            unloadPopupBox();
        });

        $("#popup_box").click( function () {
                  e.stopPropagation();
        });



        $('#global_wrapper').click( function() {
            unloadPopupBox(); 
        }); 
        $('.secure').click( function() {
            loadPopupBox(); 
        });

    });

       function unloadPopupBox() {    // TO Unload the Popupbox
            $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
            $("#container").css({ // this is just for style        
                "opacity": "1"  
            }); 
        }    

        function loadPopupBox() {    // To Load the Popupbox
            $('#popup_box').show();
            $("#container").css({ // this is just for style
                "opacity": "0.3"  
            });         
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't passing the event to the click handler, try updating this event handler, note the e passed as a parameter to the function:

```
$("#popup_box").click( function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: you need to also stopPropogation() inside of $('secure').click... because technically the you are also clicking on the #global_wrapper (which will hide your pop-up, again.